# Trouble reading a comma-terminated string in

Tags: c, csv

I have a function that reads in a file that looks like the following into a structure. I'm trying to make sure that the structure is being filled properly; and, it is filled correctly for Gender, Height, and Weight. However, I'm having trouble verifying that the Name (character array) part of it is filling properly.

Example file to read in:

```
Name,Gender,Height,Weight
Tanner,M,71.8,180.25
John,M,70.75,185.3
Parker,F,65.25,120.3
Meeks,M,57.25,210.2
Big,M,57.5,150.1
Jackson,F,52.1,163.4
```

Struct Definition:

```
struct canData
{
    char name[50];
    char gender;
    float height;
    float weight;
}CD[structSize]; // end struct BP
```

Part of the loop that reads the file in:

```
char name[50];
    char gender;
    float height;
    float weight;
    int position = 0;

filePtr = fopen(fileName, "r"); // open file
    if (filePtr == NULL) // error check opening file
    {
        printf("Opening file failed. Please reenter filename.");
        exit(1); // WILL THIS RETURN TO MENU?
    } // end if

// skip header line of file
    char buffer[100];
    fgets(buffer, 100, filePtr);

while (fscanf(filePtr, "%[^,], %[^,], %f, %f", &name, &gender, &height, &weight) == 4) // read in
    {
        printf("%s\n", name); // DEBUG ATTEMPT
        printf("%s\n", CD[position].name); // DEBUG ATTEMPT
        printf("%f\n", weight); // DEBUG ATTEMPT

        strcpy(CD[position].name, name);
        CD[position].gender = gender;
        CD[position].height = height;
        CD[position].weight = weight;
        position++;
        iCount++;



    } // end while
```

Currently, my output is as follows:

```
(space where name should be)
(space where CD[position].name should be)
180.25
(space where name should be)
(space where CD[position].name should be)
185.3
(space where name should be)
(space where CD[position].name should be)
120.3
(space where name should be)
(space where CD[position].name should be)
...
```

Thanks for any insight! I'm a C beginner, so I may be missing something silly.

Comment: What are types of `name`, `gender`, `height` and `weight`? Are you sure you are not invoking *undefined behavior* by passing pointers to object having wrong type?

Comment: Are you sure `CD[position].name` in the DEBUG ATTEMPT initialized? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You print `CD[position].name` _before_ the `strcpy`. Also, try `while (fscanf(filePtr, " %[^,], %[^,], %f, %f", name, gender, &height, &weight) == 4)`

Comment: @MikeCAT sorry, I had omitted some code. Yes, the types of `name`, etc. are initialized. I believe that `CD[position.name]` is initialized -- you can see in my OP that the `struct` is defined globally. I actually tried to make it minimal by omitting the initialization and such, but now I see that was a bit silly of me.

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks, I fixed that in my debugging code. Also, I did try removing & from the name variable in the while loop. Now, my program crashes instead of simply showing spaces. I'll look into this though, maybe it's closer.

Comment: `gender` is capable to store only one character, so only zero characters can be read, considering the terminating null-character.

Comment: @MikeCAT What you're saying about `gender` makes sense to me; however, with my current code, if I try to print out `gender` it works correctly and prints M or F. I have it initialized as a simple char, not a char[], if that matters.

Comment: @MomoDevi It seems that it *happened to seem working*. Do not access where is not allocated. Use `%c` to read single character.

Comment: @MikeCAT funny, changing it to %c for the char fixed the original problem. Thanks for the lesson in unintended behavior.

Comment: You correctly have a space before the second `%[^ ]`; you also need one before the first, to gobble up stray newlines left at the end of the previous input.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` expects a pointer to initial byte of an array, when you are reading a string.  So dont use`&` when you are passing as an argument.  `fscanf(fp, "%[^,]", name)` should work.

`name` will be converted to a pointer when used in  an expression.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html

Comment: "`name` itself is a pointer in your code." No, `name` is not a pointer but an array. Arrays used in expressions are ordinally converted to a pointer to its first element. Commonly-used exceptions are operand of `sizeof` operator and unary `&` operator.