# Storing .txt file into structures

Tags: c

I'm trying to store the .txt file into struct, not being successful.
I dont need the first line stored, but I do need the rest.
Thanks guys !! =)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    struct candidates
    {
        char name[25];
        char gender[5];
        int height;
        int weight;
    };

    struct candidates values[25];

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp=fopen("candidatesdata.txt","r"))==NULL){printf("Unable to open file\n");}


    int x = 0;
    int iterations = 0;
    while((fscanf(fp,"%s,%s,%d,%d",&values[x].name, &values[x].gender, &values[x].height, &values[x].weight))!=EOF)
        {
            x++;
            iterations +=1;
        }
    fclose(fp);

    //values[15].weight = 300;

    printf("\n%d\t%d",iterations,values[1].height);


    return 0;
}
```

Text file looks like the following:

```
Name,Gender,Height,Weight
Tanner,M,71.8,180.25
John,M,70.75,185.3
Parker,F,65.25,120.3
Meeks,M,57.25,210.2
```

Comment: And your question/error is?

Comment: your `fscanf` expects integers for height and weight, but they're obviously floatin numbers.

Comment: no wonder, but the struct still doesn't store the data in the txt right

Comment: Hello, World!

21      -2147483648
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.462 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: thats my output   =(

Comment: Skip field-name line.

Comment: Oh ok thanks guys, where should i put field-name?

Comment: head of file. It skip.

Comment: Given a data file “candidatesdata.txt”, write a C program that collects the
information listed below:
(The “candidatesdata.txt” file have the following format:
Name,Gender,Height,Weight
Tanner,M,71.8,180.25

Comment: use `%24[^,]` instead of `%s` for `name` (`%4[^,] for `gender`). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963294/trouble-reading-a-comma-terminated-string-in

Comment: I appreciate it everyone, still working on it =)

Comment: @DavidG. I made fix sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct candidates
    {
        char name[25];
        char gender[5]; // can be char gender too !!
        int height; // should be changed to float height
        int weight; // should be changed to float height
    };
```

If you **actually** have :

```
Name,Gender,Height,Weight
```

in your file, you might do  his before you go to the while loop :

```
char somebigstring[100];
.
.
.
if(fscanf(fp,"%s",somebigstring) == EOF) //wasting the first line
   exit(-1); // exiting here if there is no first line
```

Comment: oh i see, i guess i could do a do/while loop

Answer (score 0):

This code does two following things; first is writes data into .txt file and the second it reads data from .txt file and stores in struct data type which is what you are trying achieve but only for single entity. Next you should implement this as for entities.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[30];
    //other fields
}Candidate;

typedef struct{
    Candidate c;
    char city[30];
    int vote;
}CityVotes;

//for .bin operations
void write_to_file(FILE *f)
{
    Candidate c;
    CityVotes cv;

    printf("Enter candidate name : ");
    scanf("%s",&c.name);
    cv.c = c;
    printf("Enter the city : ");
    scanf("%s",&cv.city);
    printf("Enter the vote : ");
    scanf("%d",&cv.vote);
    fwrite(&cv, sizeof(cv), 1, f);
}
//for .txt operations
void write_to_file1(FILE *f)
{
    Candidate c;
    CityVotes cv;

    printf("Enter candidate name : ");
    scanf("%s",c.name);
    cv.c = c;
    printf("Enter the city : ");
    scanf("%s",&cv.city);
    printf("Enter the vote : ");
    scanf("%d",&cv.vote);
    fprintf(f,"%s ", cv.c.name);
    fprintf(f,"%s ", cv.city);
    fprintf(f,"%d ", cv.vote);
}
//for .bin operations
void read_file(FILE *f)
{
    CityVotes cv;
    while(fread(&cv, sizeof(cv), 1, f)){
        printf("Candidate : %s\t",cv.c.name);
        printf("City.: %s\t",cv.city);
        printf("Vote.: %d\n",cv.vote);
    }
}
//for .txt operations
void read_file1(FILE *f){
    CityVotes cv;
    fscanf(f," %s", &cv.c.name);
    fscanf(f," %s", &cv.city);
    fscanf(f," %d", &cv.vote);

    printf("Candidate : %s\t",cv.c.name);
    printf("City.: %s\t",cv.city);
    printf("Vote.: %d\n",cv.vote);
}
int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("candidates.txt","w");
    write_to_file1(f);
    fclose(f);
    f=fopen("candidates.txt","r");
    read_file1(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Be aware, the code just is example , you should check for nulls.

Comment: No explanation of code could lead to further questions, for instance why have a `Candidate` struct when the `CityVotes` struct could just have another `char[]`. This answer is better suited as a comment with a link to the question you answered.

Comment: That is right, you can get rid of that struct and place a char[] in CityVotes but he or she may want to add more fields to it which will make sense in Candidate struct but not in CityVotes. e.g -> gender, height, age etc.

Answer (score 0):

fix like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct candidates{
    char name[25];
    char gender[7];//Female+1
    float height;
    float weight;
};

int main(void) {
    struct candidates values[25];

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp=fopen("candidatesdata.txt","r"))==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[64];
    int x = 0;
    int iterations = 0;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)){
        iterations += 1;
        if(x < 25 && sscanf(line, "%24[^,],%6[^,],%f,%f", values[x].name, values[x].gender, &values[x].height, &values[x].weight)==4){
            x++;
        } else if(iterations != 1){
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid data in %d line: %s", iterations, line);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        printf("%s,%c,%.2f,%.2f\n", values[i].name, *values[i].gender, values[i].height, values[i].weight);
    }

    return 0;
}
```